# Null value in Angular material md-datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

Is it possible to set a **null value** to an **md-datepicker** ?

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="vm.activity.myDate" md-placeholder="myDate" />
```

in my controller I tried to set date to null but it always show **1/1/1901**

```
if (row.entity.DataSchedulazione == '')
    row.entity.DataSchedulazione = null;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and it doesn't show 1/1/1901. [CodePen link](http://codepen.io/kgfaith/pen/bpMbdO)

Your code is setting null to

```
row.entity.DataSchedulazione
```

, instead of vm.activity.myDate though.

Answer (score 0):

> Set null in your model value  `vm.activity.myDate = null;`